# Tag creation request

Tags: support, tagging

If this is not the best place to answer this question, please advise where would be.

Can someone with a high enough reputation score please create the `ipsec` tag? I was browsing tags and adding the descriptions for the ones that are missing a description. There are currently 156 questions with this tag but to editable tag wiki.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The tag is there, so I don't think it needs to be created. I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @RonMaupin You are correct, the other day when I tried to edit the tag it said it didn't exist, maybe a weird bug? I can edit it now so I will do so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag already existed, for some reason I couldn't edit it but now I can so the problem is resolved.